# Assessing Cannibalisation from new products

Tags: difference-in-difference

I have a very interesting topic to investigate but face problems on econometric identification strategy. I need no fancy estimations but just a way to deal with the issue.

For a snacks producer I have data on quantity, prices and revenue (q*p) by 6 different retail chains. In the data are a portfolio of existing products for the snack producer, new innovations (new types of flavours) and the same data on the biggest competitors.

My intuition tells me that a DIF-IN-DIF specification would be a good starting point as some new products are only introduced in some of the retail chains and that could help identify the effect on existing sales by introducing the new product.

monthly_sales_snacksproducer = B0 + B1_new_innovation + +B2_time_postinnovation + B1*B2 ("treatment effect").

I guess I will need to control for competitor sales and time fixed effects as well. The LHS variable could be changed to market

Does anyone have comments to this approach? And is there a way to analyse the effect of the innovations that are introduced across all chains?

Thanks for all help! Very much appreciated.